# Generate a random number from 2 ranges of numbers in php

Tags: php

My current code generates 116 random numbers between the range of 34 and 76 and puts them into an array called $common.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 116; $i++){
    $common[] = mt_rand(34, 76);
}
```

Is it possible to generate a random number from 2 groups of numbers?  For instance, I want to have it pick 116 random numbers between 1-22 and 34-76.

Comment: `for($i = 0; $i < 116; $i++){ if (mt_rand(1, 2) > 1)
    $common[] = mt_rand(1, 22); else $common[] = mt_rand(34, 76);
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Here's one way:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 116; $i++){
    $common[] = array(mt_rand(1, 22), mt_rand(34, 76))[mt_rand(0, 1)];
}
```

- Create an array of two random numbers, one from each range
- Randomly pick array index 0 or 1

### 2. Well I'm bored, here's another:

```
$range = array_merge(range(1, 22), range(34, 76));

for($i = 0; $i < 116; $i++){
    $common[] = $range[array_rand($range)];
}
```

- Create an array of the numbers in the two ranges
- Loop and randomly select from the range

In the second example you can also use:

```
$common[] = $range[mt_rand(0, count($range)-1)];
```

### 3. I'm waiting for lunch so here's another, similar to the first:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 116; $i++){
    $common[] = mt_rand(0, 1) ? mt_rand(1, 22) : mt_rand(34, 76);
}
```

- If random falsey 0 then generate from the first range
- If random truthy 1 then generate from the second range

Comment: Your second option is much better.

Comment: That was my original thought, make an array of each range, merge them, and then take a random number from that.  Wasn't sure if there was a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: How about the third?